# Delete First and Second Period While Keeping Everything in Between (Linux)

Tags: linux, shell

User calls script along with input `XX.XX.XX.XX` where `X's` are numbers.
I'm trying to extract the second set of `XX` from the left.

I've looked at examples where doing:

```
${1%.*}  <- deletes the last . and everything else after
${1##*.} <- deletes last . and everything before
```

But without an explanation on what the special characters do, I'm having trouble solving my problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Using awk:**

```
x='12.34.56.78'
awk -F '.' '{print $2}' <<< "$x"
34
```

**Using pure BASH (arrays):**

```
n=$(IFS='.' read -ra arr <<< "$x" && echo "${arr[1]}") && echo "$n"
34
```

**Using pure BASH without arrays 1:**

```
y="${x#*.}"
echo "${y%%.*}"
34
```

**Using pure BASH without arrays 2:**

```
n=$(IFS='.' && set -- $x && echo "$2") && echo "$n"
34
```

**Using sed:**

```
sed 's/^[^.]*\.\([^.]*\).*$/\1/' <<< "$x"
34
```

Comment: These worked, thank you! Just out of curiosity, if I was trying to work it out using the examples I had, how would I do it?

Comment: You're welcome. See the code under **Using pure BASH without arrays** I believe that is how you were trying.

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out how the # * and . work together. Could you explain?

Comment: `y="${x#*.}"` means remove everything until first dot is found hence `y` becomes `34.56.78` then `echo "${y%%.*}"` means delete longest match after dot from right hence `y` becomes `34`.

Answer (score 1):

Pure old Bourne shell:

```
(IFS=. ; set $1; echo "$2")
```

You could also do the string substitution piecemeal:

```
x=${1#*.}
echo "${x%%.*}"
```

Answer (score 0):

here the your input XX.XX.XX.XX length is same and you need  indexes of 3,4

```
XX.XX.XX.XX 
01234567... //indexes  


x="12.34.56.78"
result=${x:3:4} 
echo $result
```

result will be 34